# Is there any possible way to style Relative Layouts using styles.xml in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-relativelayout

Instead of setting the layout_toRightof, layout_toLeftof, layout_above and layout_below parameters everytime a view is created, is there a way to include it in the styles.xml file such that it becomes easier to implement instead of typing it every single time? This is the intended layout.

[image: This is the intended layout]

I've included my activityMain.xml and styles.xml files below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="24dp"
    tools:context="com.example.android.musiclibrary.MainActivity"
    android:background="#fcfcfc">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            style="@style/song_group">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/n30_Seconds_to_Mars"
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail1"
                style="@style/icon"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail1"
                android:text="Up In The Air"
                android:id="@+id/song1"
                style="@style/song"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail1"
                android:text="30 seconds to Mars"
                style="@style/artist"
                />    
        </RelativeLayout>    
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here's my styles.xml file

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>    

<style name="icon">
    <item name="android:scaleType">fitCenter</item>
    <item name="android:maxWidth">42dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">42dp</item>
    <item name = "android:adjustViewBounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
</style>

<style name="song">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
</style>

<style name="artist">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentBottom">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
</style>

<style name="song_group">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
</style>

</resources>
```